# Sum a list of values with no separator in HTML and Java

Tags: java, html

I have a list of variable values that I need to sum and display in HTML.

For example:

```
75.00 470.00 500.00
```

The total I need to display would be `1045` or `1045.00`

Am I right in that these are two operations, first to split the list and put separators in, and then to sum the values?

Comment: You do have a separator. It is whitespace, ` `.

Comment: Is it a list or a string..

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method of String, and then parse each entry with [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

```
    String s  = "75.00 470.00 500.00";
    String[] split = s.split(" ");
    double sum = 0;
    for (String string : split) {
        sum += Double.parseDouble(string);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks will try this later. You guys on here are great!

Answer (score 0):

@xavier solution is great this is just another point of view.

```
   String strDatos=""75.00 470.00 500.00";";
   StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(strDatos, " ");//second parameter specify separator
    double sum = 0;
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
         String str=tokens.nextToken();
         sum+=Double.valueOf(str).doubleValue();
    }
```